# How to sort infinite event streams using reactive programming?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, reactivex

**Problem Statement:**

I have the following stream, 1,2,4,6,3,5.... I expect the events reached to the subscribers as 123456...

For Simplicity:

1. There cannot be possibility where one element is missing i.e you will not have 1,2,3,4,5,6...
2. The sent messages can be deleted from in-memory data structure giving space for the others.
3. This is a infinite stream, sometime may be large enough to be stored everything in memory(May be at the worst case lead to memory-exception which is fine.
4. You can pile up the events using `window(n)` or other methods, but then the events are expected to be published in sequence.

With respect to my code,
I have a `Flowable` that gets inbound data with events. These events are not in order. These messages are expected to reach subscribers in order(ascending order of event ID).

Please let me know

- how can I achieve this either using rxJava or without rx?
- What could be the optimal design for this without any event loss?

Comment: Please provide more context. You need a finite source, gather it up and sort it, with or without RxJava.

Comment: @akarnokd this is a infinite stream, sometime may be large enough to be stored in memory.

Comment: Have looked at the operators buffer and sort?